# Symmetric difference of a set and its n-th preimage

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory, induction

I have a question about the following statement:

Let $X$ be a set and $f:X\to X$ a map, then for any subset $A\subset X$ and all $n\in\mathbb{N}$

$$A\triangle f^{-n}(A)\subseteq\bigcup_{i=0}^{n-1}f^{-i}(A)\triangle f^{-(i+1)}(A).\tag{$\ast$}$$

I think I have a proof for this statement but it seems a bit convoluted:

Proceeding via induction, the case $n=1$ is clear; now, assume $(\ast)$ holds for all $1\leq k\leq n$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$, then

\begin{align*}
A\triangle f^{-(n+1)}(A) &= \underbrace{[A\cap f^{-(n+1)}(A)^c]}_{:=(1)}\cup\underbrace{[f^{-(n+1)}(A)\cap A^c]}_{=:(2)}.
\end{align*}
We investigate (1) and (2) separately.
\begin{align*}
(1) = A\cap f^{-(n+1)}(A)^c&= [A\cap(f^{-n}(A)\cup f^{-n}(A)^c)]\cap f^{-(n+1)}(A)^c\\
&= [(A\cap f^{-n}(A))\cup (A\cap f^{-n}(A)^c)]\cap f^{-(n+1)}(A)^c\\
&=(A\cap f^{-n}(A)\cap f^{-(n+1)}(A)^c)\cup (A\cap f^{-n}(A)^c\cap f^{-(n+1)}(A)^c)\\
&\subseteq (f^{-n}(A)\cap f^{-(n+1)}(A)^c)\cup(A\cap f^{-n}(A)^c).
\end{align*}
With an anologous argument for (2) (writing $A^c=A^c\cap(f^{-n}(A)\cup f^{-n}(A)^c)$) we find
\begin{align*}
(2)\subseteq(A^c\cap f^{-n}(A))\cup (f^{-(n+1)}\cap f^{-n}(A)^c).
\end{align*}
Hence
\begin{align*}
A\triangle f^{-(n+1)}(A)&\subseteq [(f^{-n}(A)\cap f^{-(n+1)}(A)^c)\cup(A\cap f^{-n}(A)^c)]\cup[(A^c\cap f^{-n}(A))\cup (f^{-(n+1)}\cap f^{-n}(A)^c)]\\
&= A\triangle f^{-n}(A)\cup f^{-n}(A)\triangle f^{-(n+1)}(A)\\
&\overset{(\ast)}{\subseteq}\bigcup_{i=0}^{n-1}f^{-i}(A)\triangle f^{-(i+1)}(A)\cup f^{-n}(A)\triangle f^{-(n+1)}(A)\\
&=\bigcup_{i=0}^{n}f^{-i}(A)\triangle f^{-(i+1)}(A),
\end{align*}
which proves the claim.

Now, I think the proof feels a bit convoluted. This proof is just a small supplementary result for a 90-minute seminar that I'm going to give and I don't want to spend that much time on it, since there's a lot more material to cover. I was wondering if there is a *slicker* way of getting the result. If you have any ideas, let me know. Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

A simple proof might show that for any sets $A,B,C$ we have $A \triangle B \subseteq A \triangle C \cup C \triangle B$. Your statement then follows immediately by adding in all intermediate sets and does not require any properties of the pre-image:
$$A \triangle f^{-n}(A) \subseteq A \triangle f^{-1} (A) \cup f^{-1} (A)\triangle f^{-n} (A) \dots \subseteq \bigcup_{i=0}^{n-1} f^{-i} (A)\triangle f^{-(i+1)} (A)$$